# Clearing md-radio-button selections in Angular 2 App

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, radio-button, angular-material2

I have a sorting filter set up on my Angular app, that uses radio buttons via md-radio-group so that users can choose a preferred sorting method on a table display of data. The radio buttons are working as expected. However, I also have a "Restore Defaults" button that I want to use to clear all radio-button selections and return to default sorting. So far I'm having difficulty getting the radio buttons to clear.

This is what my view code looks like:

```
    <filter-option name="Sort"
            placeholder="Select Sorting Option"
            [usePlaceholder]="!value"
            [visible]="sortFilters.enabled">
        <filter-label>{{value | capitalize}}</filter-label>
        <filter-menu>
            <md-radio-group class="mat-radio-label-content">
                <md-radio-button value="alphabetical" class="vert-radiobox-list" (click)="onSortClicked(value = 'alphabetical')">
                    Alphabetical
                </md-radio-button>
                <md-radio-button value="reverse alphabetical" class="vert-radiobox-list" (click)="onSortClicked(value = 'reverse alphabetical')">
                    Reverse Alphabetical
                </md-radio-button>
                <md-radio-button value="numeric ID" class="vert-radiobox-list" (click)="onSortClicked(value = 'numeric ID')">
                    Numeric ID
                </md-radio-button>
            </md-radio-group>
            <button md-button class="restore-button" (click)="clearSortingFilters()">Restore Defaults</button>
        </filter-menu>
    </filter-option>
```

In my component I have this that initializes the filter:

```
sortFilters =
{
    enabled: true,
    value: false
};
```

And this is the function attached to the button to clear the sort filters:

```
clearSortingFilters()
{
    this.sendSort.emit(this.value = '');
}
```

Now, in the above function, `this.sendSort.emit(this.value = '')` accomplishes clearing the selection that was showing in the filter-label area. But how do I clear the md-radio-group radio button selections as well?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is how you should modify your code in order to work:

### html

```
<md-radio-group class="mat-radio-label-content" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue">
     <md-radio-button value="alphabetical" class="vert-radiobox-list" (click)="onSortClicked(value = 'alphabetical')">
           Alphabetical
     </md-radio-button>
     <md-radio-button value="reverse alphabetical" class="vert-radiobox-list" (click)="onSortClicked(value = 'reverse alphabetical')">
           Reverse Alphabetical
     </md-radio-button>
     <md-radio-button value="numeric ID" class="vert-radiobox-list" (click)="onSortClicked(value = 'numeric ID')">
           Numeric ID
     </md-radio-button>
</md-radio-group>    
<button md-button class="restore-button" (click)="clearSortingFilters()">Restore Defaults</button>
```

### ts

```
selectedValue: string;

clearSortingFilters(){
    this.selectedValue = null; // or false or ''
  }
```

Working plunkr [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/v5NLHIlOnOM58iZQ5mUS?p=preview)

Comment: Perfect. Thanks @BogdanC!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you would want to add NgModel to your input value. Something like this: [(ngModel)]="reverse alphabetical". Also you might want to change your OnClick function to change the value of "reverse alphabetical" to false.